# Getting A NumberFormat Exception in BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, numberformatexception

I am trying to parse a string to int value. But i am getting a NumberFormat Exception. I am writing the below code:

```
     Logger.out("Myprof", "Contact "+strContact);
    try{
        i = Integer.parseInt(strContact.trim());
        Logger.out("Myprof", "Contact8686866      "+i);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logger.out("Myprof", "exce "+e.toString());
    }
```

Now when i am passing like below:

```
i = Integer.parseInt("11223344");
```

I am getting the i value as 11223344.

Where i am doing wrong here?  Please Help.

Comment: It is likely that `strContact` contains non numeric characters or is empty. Output the variable before attempting to parse it. What does the full stacktrace tell you?

Comment: strContact is a String. It is giving the proper value in this line: Logger.out("Myprof", "Contact "+strContact);

Comment: it is giving me this result in this line: Myprof: - : contact 9875566521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input value of `9875566521` is greater than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) of `2147483647`. Instead use a `Long`.  (`BigInteger` not an option for Blackberry)

```
Long number = Long.parseLong(strContact);
Logger.out("Myprof", "Contact8686866 " + number);
```

If the intended input numbers are greater then `Long.MAX_VALUE`, then [Character.iDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) can be used as an alternative to validate values:

```
private static boolean isValidNumber(String strContact) {
   for (int i = 0; i < strContact.length(); i++) {
      if (!Character.isDigit(strContact.charAt(i))) {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: BigInteger is not available for BlackBerry. So if i will enter the value as 21345, then it should be able to parse. I will try this.

Comment: If your numbers are _very_ large, then you will be better served checking each of the digits individually using `Character.isDigit`

Comment: yes when i am giving 1234567890, it is displaying the proper value